# Not able to add a subfolder to remote repository in Github

Tags: git, github, subdirectory

In my computer I have a folder `nextdoor`, and there is subfolder inside it `source`. All my images and code are present inside the `source` folder, but somehow I am not able to push this particular subfolder to remote repository.

Remote Repository : [LINK](https://github.com/rakeshsukla53/secure-message)

If you go to remote repo, you can see the `source` folder is not added. The subfolder is also not empty. I have tried bunch of methods but unfortunately, I am not able to push this particular subfolder up.

If I do `git status`

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

**Total subfolders:**

```
bin  include  lib  local  pip-selfcheck.json  README.md  source  static_cdn
```

Since I am able to push all folders but why `source` is not going up?

Inside `source` folder:

```
crytography  manage.py  registration.txt  templates
db.sqlite3   nextdoor   static
```

**.gitignore file:**

```
# global gitignore for IDE, etc
# -- should still exclude project specific ignores in .gitignore

# system junk
.netrwhist
.Trash-1000
*.pyc
npm-debug.log

# IDEs
.idea
.env

# private files
id_rsa
*.key
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: are you sure there is no .gitignore file in your source directory?

Comment: strange... your "source" directory is not a symbolic link or something like that?

Comment: I didn't understood by symbolic link. How can I check this?

Comment: You cannot push a subfolder. You can only push commits. Either your problem is making a proper local commit or pushing that commit.

Comment: Initially I used `git add --all`, all the folders went up except `source`. Then I try to add using `git add source/` but nothing is happening. I can't commit since git is not able to add `source`.

Comment: I cloned your repository; and tried to add some files in the source directory; and it didn't work either. I only got it to work by removing your .git directory and reinitializing it (git init; git add --all)...

Comment: Did you play with submodules? Your "source" folder looks like a submodule, but `.gitmodules` is missing.

Comment: @michas I don't exactly know what is `.gitmodules`. Could you explain how to add `.gitmodules`.

Comment: @ChrisMaes You suggestion worked :) :)

Comment: PS: Thanks a lot for giving a reference to the actual repository! This allows to look at the actual facts instead of vague speculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last commit(815bb7d) is broken. It adds "half a submodule".

When adding a submodule using `git submodule add` two things happen: a file `.gitmodules` is created, containing the URL of your submodule and a "folder" is created, annotated with the commit of your submodule.

In your case you managed to create a commit containing the second, but not the first:

```
$ git ls-tree 815bb7d28719ab66e765ba8e265eb317766b68db
100644 blob 506c8957ac440449d375416f45c6753a3cb65d83    .gitignore
100644 blob 5f8188352aa817edb6808536f598d3ac74d448d7    README.md
040000 tree c336cc94ab9a686360ee9e6f330558cdee571e9d    bin
040000 tree 334b6ff5f7c516042b7a185ec6106208df8495a7    include
040000 tree e65f051d2d0e9f2648a6b83f0ef0836893423ee5    lib
040000 tree 63a79abf5f366fc25b0b47fc527ea237163a0505    local
100644 blob 2dbf660a900d007e70510ff0ccc2c553b32d6120    pip-selfcheck.json
160000 commit 4732e130e321cacd355f8bffbf1c1726e94576c6  source
040000 tree 12edc4bcf6f3ab7a76dc5bda57a940c0caeae7e0    static_cdn
```

You see, the commit object is stored but the corresponding `.gitmodules` file is not.

You have at least two options either throw away the broken commit (`git reset --hard 815bb7d28719ab66e765ba8e265eb317766b68db^`) or throw away you whole history altogether by deleting the `.git` directory as suggested in comments.

---

Be aware that it is *not* possible to push directories ever. You always do local commits in your local repository and then sync your local repository with a remote repository by pushing your local commit.

In your case you were not able to add the files in "source" to your repository, because "source" was considered as a separate repository, a submodule.

Comment: a much better solution than my "brute force" option :) you have my vote!

Answer (score -1):

This is the fastest, but surely not the best solution. Something seems to be broken in your git repository. The fastest way I got this to work was to destroy your git repository and start again. **warning** you will lose your history:

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add ...
```

I would be better to investiage **why** the git repository is broken; as suggested by @michas

Comment: @python it worked for you, but I can understand the downvote; this isn't a very nice solution: your bathroom leaks? Let's demolish the house and build a new house :)

Comment: It would be better to fix your repository. ;)